# Display Recipient Email in Unsubscribe HTML

Tags: php, email, sendgrid, unsubscribe, sendgrid-templates

I have set the unsubscribe HTML body from the settings of sendgrid. The only issue I am getting is to display the email which is being unsubscribed. Tried the placeholders in the following attached image but none of them worked. Also, couldn't find anything in the documentation.

[image]

So, how to display an email of a user being unsubscribed in the customized HTML?